# Serving files on a local network with Deno

Tags: http, localhost, deno

I recently decided to play around with [Deno](https://deno.land/) a bit.

Right now I am trying to set up a basic file server on my local network, but it will only serve files to my computer and not the rest of the network (I can't even send a http request to the server from outside my computer). I can not, for the life of me, figure out why it only works locally.

I have added the code I am using at the moment below just in case, but I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere else, because I have the same problem with [this file_server example](https://deno.land/std/http/file_server.ts) and when I create a file server with [oak](https://github.com/oakserver/oak)

```
import { serve } from 'https://deno.land/std@v0.42.0/http/server.ts';
const server = serve({ port: 3000 });

const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

for await (const req of server) {
    const filePath = 'public' + req.url;

    try {
        const data = await Deno.readFile(filePath);
        req.respond({ body: decoder.decode(data) });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === Deno.errors.NotFound.name) {
            console.log('File "' + filePath + '" not found');
            req.respond({ status: 404, body: 'File not found' });
        } else {
            req.respond({ status: 500, body: 'Rest in pieces' });
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

The command I'm using to run  the file is:

```
deno --allow-all server.ts
```

When I create a simple file server in Node.js everything works just fine. It can serve files to my computer and any other device on the network.

I think the fault is with my understanding of Deno and it's security concepts, but I don't know. I would greatly appreciate any help and can supply more details if required.

Comment: This was a bug that was fixed a few days after your post. Now `0.0.0.0` is the default hostname. See https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/5203

Comment: This is no longer worked since [std@0.107.0](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/blob/0.107.0/http/server.ts) has refactor the `serve` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the hostname to `0.0.0.0` like so :

`const server = serve({ hostname: '0.0.0.0', port: 3000 });`

By default, your webserver only responds to `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.

Binding to `0.0.0.0` tells Deno to bind to all IP addresses/interfaces on your machine. Which makes it accessible to any machine on your network.

Your network IP address in the format of `192.168.x.y.` gets also bind to the Deno webserver which allows another computer in your network to access the webserver with your local IP address.

Comment: Nice, it works perfect. The problem seems to have been my limited grasp of network concepts then...